# Counting the number of functions and data structures in a C codebase

Tags: c

Is there a way to take a C file (or a directory/project) and count the number of functions + data structures? This is similar to counting the LOC but instead is focused on counting the number of "conceptual units" the program handles as a way to measure its complexity.

Comment: Yes...  Take a look at _[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)_.

Comment: *Why* do you want it?

Comment: @wildplasser: I'm guessing, it's to encourage programmers to write millions of single-line functions (to artificially inflate their "number of conceptual units" scores). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are in need of perusing your source code.  *[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html)* is an excellent tool for summarizing just about every aspect of a C project.  (and many other languages).  It is OpenSource, and easily downloaded.  Additionally, the *[list of features](http://mcs.une.edu.au/doc/doxygen/html/features.html)* is extensive.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux environment, you'll want to look at a tool like [`objdump`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-objdump/), that will show you a bunch of information about the compiled output.

There are pages that explain some of its complicated output, such as [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-objdump-command/).
But perhaps one of the simplest is `objdump -T`.